# creating a transparent flame

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

I was trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtR5sCpZd3M) to create flames but no matter what I try I can't get my texture to be transparent. what am I doing wrong? I've rewatched the tutorial multiple times and I think I've done every step ‍♀️ I'd greatly appreciate some help. thanks!!

[image: flame texture]
[image: material options]
[image: node chart]
[image: the rest of the nodes]

Comment: you might want to use greya, a .png, saw the color ramp itll load faster

Comment: @LeeOswald Beginners might not really understand "shorthand" explanations. I guess you mean a greyscale image with alpha channel (entering "greya" at Google gives no useful results and "grey-a" gives definitely other results than what you meant here). Apart from that the only thing you tell is replacing a Voronoi texture with an image which 1. doesn't help if one has no idea what kind of image or where to get something suitable, 2. will most likely not work well with the _Generated_ coordinates, 3. is limited by resolution and tiling and 4. why greyscale when the goal is that cartoon look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For beginners, I can only recommend to thoroughly watch tutorials and pay close attention to what they are doing there. The answer is quite simple: you are using a *Translucent BSDF* in your material, but what you need is a *Transparent BSDF*. Translucency and transparency are not the same.

[image: translucency vs. transparency]

Comment: that was the problem, thank you! I didn't realize there were two different ones. there's no need to be rude though, as you said I'm a beginner and I'm trying 

Answer (score -2):

alpha hashed is my go to

the image does not have the leftmost node, we could help better with a full node picture! but if you make it an rgba image with gimp it works.

principled bsdf has alpha channel, try that

Comment: I added another screenshot that shows the full node setup. I don't have an image, it's a voronoi texture node

Comment: Of course there are different methods to do transparency in _Eevee_, but the real question here is not what alternatives are there but what is wrong with the setup, because it works in the tutorial with _Alpha Clip_. Also this is more a comment than a real answer... The solution is quite simple, see my answer.

Comment: For the reasons given in my other comment, this answer would be greatly improved with an illustration,  a full description of your recommended approach, and an explanation of _why_  you recommend it. The part that's a fair criticism of the question is not a part of the answer, and should, instead, be a comment. If this attracts downvotes, it will be because, in the  Stack Exchange environment, it's considered incomplete, and in part, not strictly relevant to answering the question.  SE sites have quite a strict structure.. I hope this comment begins to explain it.